# How to get address of C++ Char Datatype

Tags: c++

In the lesson I'm going through it uses this to record the address of a `char` value...

```
char givenChar;
std::cout<<"character = \n";
std::cin>>givenChar;

std::cout<< "address character = " << (void *) &givenChar<<"\n\n";
```

But it does not explain at all what is happening here to get `address character = 0x7ffd812a9257`.

what is the `(void *)` called and what is it doing?

Comment: Note we should be using c++ style casting, static_cast<void*>(&givenChar). As an aside from the question at hand.

Comment: another good practice is to use `std::addressof` to get the address instead of  operator `&`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stuff something into an output-stream (`std::ostream`) like `std::cout`, the stream insertion operator `<<` is used:

```
std::cout << "Hello, World!";
```

The stream insertion operator that is called for string literals like `"Hello, World"` looks like

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const char* s);
```

As you can see, the 2nd parameter is a pointer to `const char`. Now if you would write

```
char givenChar;
std::cout << &givenChar;
```

the address-of operator `&` would give you the address of `givenChar`. The type of this address is `char*` which is convertible into a `char const*`. So the above mentioned function

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const char* s);
```

would be called (like `operator<<(std::cout, &givenChar)`) which would interpret the memory at the location of the address of `givenChar` as a zero-terminated string. Eg. it would read from the memory until it finds a `'\0'`. But at the address of `givenChar` is only space for *one* `char` which most likely is not zero. This would result in garbage inserted into `std::cout` (=printed) and eventually lead to an access violation.

So instead you use

```
char givenChar;
std::cout << (void*) &givenChar;
```

`(void*)` is a cast. It converts the `char*` produced by applying the address-of operator `&` to the `char` `givenChar` into a pointer to `void`. For a `void*` the operator

```
ostream& operator<<(void* val);
```

gets called which will only insert the numeric value of the given address into the stream instead of trying to print a string that might exist at the address.

Comment: Thank you for that amazing write-up. wow. Wish maybe you could elaborate on, "This would result in garbage inserted into std::cout (=printed) and eventually lead to an access violation."

Comment: @MichaelRader When `operator<<(std::ostream&, char const*)` tries to interpret the pointer you feed it as a zero terminated string it will not only read `givenChar` and print it, but it will then try to read the char at `&givenChar + 1`, check if it is 0 stop else print it. and again for the char at `&givenChar + 2`, and for `&givenChar + 3` and so on. First thing is that your program doesn't own this memory `operator<<` is going to read so it is undefined behaviour what happens, the other thing is that noone can predict which values there are in the memory after `givenChar` since it hasn't

Comment: @MichaelRader been initialized nor written to before. Verstehste?

Answer (score 2):

In C++ operators work based on the types of their operands. Here the behavior of the `<<` operator depends on [the type of] its right hand side operand.

For example, if you want to print out an integer with `cout << 1`, the string `1` will be printed. If on the other hand the operand is a pointer then the output will be in hexadecimal and will have a `0x` prefix.

If the operand is a char pointer (`&givenChar`), the behavior is also different, the operator will print the characters starting from that address until the first zero byte.

If you want to print the address of a character, you need to have a void pointer to achieve that. To have a void pointer, you need to cast the char *: `(void *) givenChar`.